# Should I replace my oil bath air filter with a normal one?

Tags: air-filter

I have a 1959 Nash Metropolitan with an oil bath air filter. Would you recommend just leaving it alone or should I replace it with a modern air filter? (The replacement looks the same from the outside so I'm not worried about the appearance.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iwould say yes but only from the ecological point of view.Eliminating the solvents needed to clean the filter and the ease of replacement would be two strong points.

Comment: I'd say yes because you're likely to get better filtration with a modern filter.  Even contemporary oiled air filters don't work as well as pleated paper filters (although they do flow more air).